# Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault nothing work

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, pygame, pyserial

I'm having this  error sometimes:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Some times when a run the program I received this error, but I received this error before use the pygame, and the try,except doesn't catch nothing.
I'm making a program with this configuration. 
I do not know what else to do, please help.:

```
Windows 10 64bits

python 2.7 64bits

pygame. __version__: '1.9.3'

Tkinter.__version__: '$Revision: 81008 $'

ttk.__version__: '0.3.1'

pickle.__version__: '$Revision: 72223 $'

pyserial.__version__: '2.7'
```

Comment: Please upload a sample code

Comment: Sorry, isn't possible, I'm not the owner...
but the program send and received commands by serial, and update some labels.
I'm using the pygame only in a thread that received commands from an bluetooth joystick,make some math, update labels, and send info for serial.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using the method.

```
Tkinter.after()
```

looks like I was having a race condition for greatly changing the screen. I tested by 2 hours and haven't an error.